# Tabs open on current day in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, tabs

I'm building a TV listing and and I'm using tab shortcode with tabs:

- Monday
- Tuesday
- Wednesday
- Thursday
- Friday
- Saturday
- Sunday

Every tab shows a node that have a TV listing.

I want that tabs will be shown according to the day

Example: today is Friday, so when a user enters the page for TV schedule the active tab will be Friday.

I found this solution: 
html:

```
    <div id="tabs">
<ul>
    <li><a href="monday.php">Monday</a></li>
    <li><a href="tuesday.php">Tuesday</a></li>
    <li><a href="wednesday.php">Wednesday</a></li>
    <li><a href="thursday.php">Thursday</a></li>
    <li><a href="friday.php">Friday</a></li>
    <li><a href="saturday.php">Saturday</a></li>
    <li><a href="sunday.php">Sunday</a></li>
</ul>
```

and javascript

```
    $('#tabs').tabs();
$('#tabs').tabs('select', ((new Date().getDay() || 7) - 1));
$('#tabs .ui-state-active a').text('Today');
```

But it don't work in wordpress. I've tried everything but this code don't want to work. I mean it works (you can see demo in link provided) but it won't on wordpress page. any idea please? Or maybe some one knows another script for this function that works in wordpress?..

Comment: SO is not a think tank - please provide us actual code and actual problems, not with "any ideas" stuff. Voting to close this question

Comment: This is actual problem and I really need actual help here, not a voting for closing down my question. It's my first question on this site and before just close anything it'd appreciate if you explain me my mistakes.... P.S. I've edited question. Hope it's in correct  shape now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that jQuery is loaded on your page. You also need to make sure that your javascript is loading after the page loads. Try putting this in your head:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

<script>
window.onload = function () {
    $('#tabs').tabs();
    $('#tabs').tabs('select', ((new Date().getDay() || 7) - 1));
    $('#tabs .ui-state-active a').text('Today');
}
</script>
```

Comment: no nothing. I've placed other javascript code in same page and it worked as normal. but this code doean't.

Comment: I've placed it in header, then in wordpress text editor itself. I don't get it why other script works and this one don't.